# How to integrate cos3θ/(5−4cosθ) from 0 to 2π?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How do you find the following integral using the theory of Residue?
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(3\theta)d\theta}{5-4\cos(\theta)}$$
I've substituted $\cos(\theta)$ and $\cos(3\theta)$ for $\frac{z+1/z}{2}$ and $\frac{z^3+1/z^3}{2}$ as well as the $d\theta$ with $\frac{dz}{iz}$ but I can't seem to get the correct answer which is $\pi/12$.

Comment: Expand $\cos3\theta$ into polynomial in terms of $\cos\theta$, then apply the Weierstrass substitution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Booh! The OP has already a better idea.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that approach doesn' t use the residue theorem... @ABC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to consider the integral

> $$I =  \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{i3\theta }d\theta}{5-4\cos(\theta)} $$

where your integral corresponds to the real part of $I$.

**Added:**

> $$ I = \int_{|z|=1} \frac{z^3}{5-2(z+1/z)}\frac{dz}{iz}. $$

Can you finish it?

Comment: I realize that there are other ways of evaluating the integral but my professor requires us to solve it using the Cauchy Residue Theorem

Comment: @Joel: Just use the same technique you are using with the integral I gave you which makes your life easier.

Comment: Why not use Cauchy Residue Theorem om the integral science posted?

Comment: Yeah, calculating the residues of quartic polynomials are so much fun... I prefer this aproach by far.

Comment: Just wondering, how did you get e^i3θ from cos(3θ). Shouldn't e^i3θ be cos(3θ)+isin(3θ)?I know it works as i got the correct answer evaluating your integral.

Comment: You need to take the real part of the integral. $\Re(e^{i 3 \theta}) = \cos 3 \theta$

Answer (score 0):

An elementary antiderivative is obtainable without complex analysis, but since you specifically asked for a solution using residue theory, I won't elaborate too much on such a method.  The idea is to write $$\cos 3\theta = 4\cos^3 \theta - 3 \cos \theta,$$ then use polynomial long division to get $$\frac{\cos 3\theta}{5-4\cos\theta} = \frac{65}{16} \cdot \frac{1}{5-4\cos \theta} - \cos^2 \theta  - \frac{5}{4}\cos \theta - \frac{13}{16}.$$  Then with the substitution $$\cos \theta = \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}, \quad d\theta = \frac{2}{1+u^2} \, du,$$ the first term gives $$\int \frac{d\theta}{5-4\cos\theta} = 2 \int \frac{1}{1+9u^2} \, du.$$  The rest is just computation.  It is altogether quite tractable, though perhaps not the most elegant approach.